# Connect to telnet via webpage

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, websocket, telnet

I'm new to telnet and sockets and right now I'm all confused over its concepts. So I can use some help here.

So far I've created a simple telnet server using *Node.js's* package *net*. Here's a little snippet of that,

```
function newSocket(socket) {
  sockets.push(socket);
  console.log('A new telnet connection!\n');
  socket.on('data', function(data) {
  });
  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('A Telnet socket disconnected!\n');
  });
}

var telnetServer = net.createServer(newSocket);
telnetServer.listen(8080);
```

It works perfectly on using command

```
telnet localhost 8080
```

and also I know I can connect to it using *net* package of NodeJS, like this

```
var client = net.connect({port: port}, function() {
    console.log('client connected');
    client.write('data!\r\n');
});
```

So, what I want to do is to connect to this telnet server from my client side application (AngularJS), if it's even possible.

I know how to connect to web sockets from AngularJS app using *$websocket* service, like this,

```
      $websocket.$new({
        url: websocketUrl,
        protocols: [],
        subprotocols: ['base46'],
        reconnect: true,
        reconnectInterval: 500
      });
```

So, my questions are:

- **Can I connect to telnet server from client-side? I mean is it even possible to connect to telnet from web browser like we do with web-sockets?**
- **If yes, can you show me some kind of snippet for that?**
- **Are web-sockets are better option than Telnet?**

I know these questions sound silly, but like I said I have just started digging around about these things.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing Telnet. TCP and WebSockets. Telnet and WebSockets are both different protocols on top of TCP.

Comment: Yes, I was confused yesterday. I found the solution after studying some more about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through various docs online, I got my answer. And as there is no answer yet (as of writing this), I am posting, what I found, one myself.

**First of all, Answers of my Questions**

> Can I connect to telnet server from client-side? I mean is it even
>   possible to connect to telnet from web browser like we do with
>   web-sockets?

No, telnet is a protocol for the server, not some way to communicate between client and server. This was my biggest confusion which pushed me to ask this question here.

> If yes, can you show me some kind of snippet for that?

Well, we can't, so no snippet.

> Are web-sockets are better option than Telnet?

Both are different, so there is no comparison.

**Solution**

So what I did is, I used

- a server to host telnet (telnet server)
- another server for web-sockets (telnet client)
- client-side (webview)

So by this approach, I established a connection between *telnet* and *websockets* (which I needed in the first place), both are hosted on different server, and the server which was listening to web-socket, acted as telnet client.

Comment: Telnet is a client-server protocol, just like any other TCP protocol.